# iOS Server Driven UI Example/Tutorial

Tags: ios, core-data, dynamic, user-interface

I have already watched `Apples's` `WWDC 2010` video of `Building a Server-driven User Experience`.

It is really a great concept but i need a simple example or tutorial to start with.

I have searched hours in `Google` for iOS Dynamic UI generation from `XML` or `JSON` based `web services` but didn't find anything useful so far.

More Information:
I am developing an iPhone application where i present user a Input Form like questionnaire with different types of question with different UI Controls to answer like Text Field, switches, image, audio, video etc.

Now I have different questionnaire for different user, I want to generate them dynamically and also store completed form in `Core Data`.

Any help or guidance to solve this problem will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanx

Comment: I am also looking for a sample, did you achieve it ? let me know

Comment: @anoop4real - no, unfortunately I didn't get any working example and I managed to do it myself, generate my own UI based on question types received from API.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share your approach?

Answer (score 2):

have you seen heroku's Core Data Buildpack video?

http://mobile.heroku.com/